# Rails 5 - 2 classes with the same name and its calling the wrong one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

## Problem

I'm using paypal-ruby-sdk and the library has a class named Plan, jokes on me because I have a model with the same name. When I'm calling any method on that model it just triggers "undefined method" because its calling paypal library.

Library: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK

Answer (score 4):

You must reference nested classes using `Parent::Child` syntax
[Paypal's Plan](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/e49b79ea1547da37cdb2da0278fdc186ce8b8089/lib/paypal-sdk/rest/data_types.rb#L2074)
is located in `PayPal::SDK::REST::Plan`

Use `PayPal::SDK::REST::Plan` to reference Paypal's Plan
Use `::Plan` to reference your Plan. (If you defined your Plan in root namespace)
(`::Plan` means `Plan` right under the root namespace)

All decent ruby libraries are structured in the following way and exposes only one constant right under the root. (`DecentModule` in this case)

```
module DecentModule
  class ClassA
  end
  class ClassB
  end
end
```

Thus, they can avoid messing up the root namespace.
So we can reference `FancyModule::ClassA`, even if we define `ClassA` in the root namespace.

Comment: Is there a way to prioritize my model class over paypal because I'm not using paypal plan class and it would take me a some time to refactor all the code.

Comment: I think you include `include PayPal::SDK::REST` in somewhere. This embed `PayPal::SDK::REST` in your code. In that case `PayPal::SDK::REST::Plan` is prioritized over `::Plan`.  
If you remove `include PayPal::SDK::REST`, `Plan` refers to your Plan.   
If you do this, you need to add namespaces to Paypal's constants. (`Payment` -> `PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment`...  etc)

Comment: I found the problem, basically I included the library on the top of the file instead of including inside the class, so included across the whole project. That's why it was calling paypal classes.